# Icon suggestion for items/accessories that are personalised

Tags: icon

Trying to think of an icon for a page that has heavy feelings of personalisation. Ideally, users see the icon and they understand that the space it links to is like their private area. But not something so simple as the typical user profile icon of a silhouette head.

Looking for something that might be related to a brainstorm of the feels and places this space would invoke:
privacy, individuality, art, quiet, ambience, tools, buttons, power, share, edit, studyroom, desks, collections, clarity, creativity, abundance

I am hoping for ideas to do with an item/accessory/scene that would get across these feels.

Answer (score 1):

What about an icon representing a diary? It fits most of the feelings you're trying to evoke. It might be hard making it look like a diary rather than just a book, but it's a starting point at least!

Answer (score 0):

Paper Plane font from 'Entypo' Picto gram Suite.